# How to increment the number value with printed object

Tags: java, increment

```
public void Achievement() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    System.out.println("\t\t\tRanking of the 10 Players");   
    PlayerInterface<Players> nameList = new PlayerListADT<Players>();
    int i=1;
    nameList.add(new Players("Jackson",10));
    nameList.add(new Players("Micheal",20));
    nameList.add(new Players("Jack",30));
    nameList.add(new Players("Percy",40));
    nameList.add(new Players("FonD",50));
    nameList.add(new Players("Tekker",60));
    nameList.add(new Players("FOMd",70));
    nameList.add(new Players("ZXC",80));
    nameList.add(new Players("PP",90));
    nameList.add(new Players("TT",100));
    nameList.add(new Players("Sam",120));

    for(int i =1; i<nameList.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("No:"+i +nameList);
    }
}
```

Actual output:

```
12 Player Jackson 10
```

Desired output:

```
No: 1 Jackson 10
No : 2 Micheal 20
```

Comment: Could you post the `toString` method of the class `Players`

Comment: public String toString() {
     
    return String.format(" Player %-10s: %-3d",firstName,completeTime);
  }

Comment: what is the `toStirng` method of `PlayerListADT`

Comment: public String toString() {
    String outputStr = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
      outputStr += playerList[index] + "\n";
    }

    return outputStr;
  }

the adt method are use to arrange to least used completeTime go to position 1

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow, sorry im not so familiar with format

Comment: edit you question and post these methods in you question

Comment: +nameList -- > +nameList[i] or nameList.get(i) what are you extending in PlayerInterface , can't understand where your current output comes from.....

Comment: From what I have got your output should be **No: Player Jackson:10 Player Micheal: 20Player Jack: 30......and so on** and not the output you have written

Comment: yes the output show all the playerlist like you said, its like 12 No: Player Jackson:10 Player Micheal: 20Player Jack: 30......and so on. the 12 value is the total length of the namelist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a desired output as :

> No: 1 Jackson: 10
>
> No: 2 Micheal: 20
>
> ..... and so on

You require to change the `toString` method of `PlayerListADT` to:

```
public String toString() { 
    String outputStr = ""; 
    for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index) { 
        outputStr += "No: "+(index+1)+" "+playerList[index] + "\n"; 
    } 
    return outputStr; 
}
```

And instead of the loop

```
for(int i =1; i<nameList.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("No:"+i +nameList);
}
```

Simply write:

```
System.out.println(nameList.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks! you have save me from spending 3 hour on this problem. Sorry for the confusing format. Thanks again, appreciated!

Comment: @ValentineZ I hope that you understand why I suggested the changes and how these changes work